# PHPexcel group rows with images

Tags: php, image, phpexcel

I need to collapse the rows with images using PHPExcel.

**grouped**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7dnc.png

**collapse rows without images**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7dnc.png#1

Now images are displayed as follows:

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName($element["product_code"]);
$objDrawing->setDescription($element["product_code"]);
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('B'.$n);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()-    >addImage($objDrawing,PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooter::IMAGE_HEADER_LEFT);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($n)->setRowHeight(113);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($n)->setOutlineLevel(1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($n)->setCollapsed(true);
```

How to collapse rows with images using PHPExcel?

Answer (score 1):

The developer documentation details how to set outlining/grouping in sections 4.6.30 (for columns) and 4.6.33 (for rows); but I've never tried it with images. As images aren't part of the cell content, but effectively hover "above" the worksheet, I suspect it wouldn't work unless you can put some grouping values in the cells "beneath" your images.